# Playing .SWF file in Silverlinght

Tags: silverlight-4.0

i am tring to play a .swf in silverlight page.i am using the telerik control like below

THis is working fine in internet explorer but in mozilla it gives the option of downloading the file rather then playing the swf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please elaborate more on your scenario. I've tried the following:

```
<UserControl x:Class="HtmlPlaceholderAndSWF.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <telerik:RadHtmlPlaceholder SourceUrl="http://www.bassfiles.net/parachute.swf" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

...and it works as expected, both in IE and FF.

[Internet Explorer](http://www.screencast.com/users/kiril/folders/Jing/media/6ecad7c3-a058-4689-b4b0-9e969e98d3e2)

[Firefox](http://www.screencast.com/users/kiril/folders/Jing/media/cdb15702-019f-4e30-8ac0-7b3f466117c0)

Probably there should be some setting in Firefox preventing you from playing SWF within the browser.

[image]

Comment: i am using the same code,but in application i dont c any swf file content type